# Different Ways to Arrange All Combinations (Without Repeats)

Tags: combinations

Are there different ways to arrange all combinations without repeats other than the following method.

number of items = 6| group size = 4

*1*,2,3,**4** | *1*,2,3,**5** | *1*,2,3,**6**

*1*,3,4,**5** | *1*,3,4,**6**

*1*,4,5,**6**

*2*,3,4,**5** | *2*,3,4,**6**

*2*,4,5,**6**

*3*,4,5,**6**

Answer (score 1):

You're missing $(1,2,4,5), (1,2,4,6), (1,2,5,6), (1,3,5,6), (2,3,5,6)$ . These along with your combinations make $15 = {6 \choose 4}$ combinations, so these are all the possibilities.

As far as different methods go, that is actually the most efficient way.

Comment: Thank you for this input. I had been doing it wrong for some time. Do you know of a way that tries to spread evenly each element of the elements to be combined along a vector of all combinations, so that 1 is equally likely to be in the first, second, third, to last possible combinations

Comment: Well, you could take the "matrix" of combinations formed by your method and look at the transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Think of it this way: there are 6 choices for the first number, 5 for the second, 4 for the third, and 3 for the fourth. 6*5*4*3=360

btw if the order matters, which I believe it does in the way you've stated the problem, you are not looking for combinations, but instead permutations.